Emergency reboot button freezes game
I am trying to create an emergency reboot button that can be accessed in every scene of my game. For that, I put this code into my globals script.
func _process(_delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Escape"):
        timer = get_tree().create_timer(5)
    if timer != null:
        if timer.timeout:
            get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://UI/main_menu.tscn")
        if Input.is_action_just_released("Escape"):
            timer = null

For some odd reason, this jumps my memory usage to an absurd amount.
Before:
After:
I thought this may be because the code is running for every object, but the profiler says there's only one call and I did some tests to further prove that wasn't the case. I thought it was creating more than timer, but it can't do that because it only runs the frame I hit escape. If anybody knows why this is happening I would love to learn why.
Also just for good practice is there a way to make variables private? I read in many places that if you prefix a variable with an _ that it would become private but I can still access it with other scripts. Is that just while the game is running or is it able to hide in the editor while writing code as well?
